# Font becomes smaller after upgrading to ios9

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9, iphone-6

I just migrated old app into xcode 7 and ios9.

But font looks smaller on iPhone 6. 
And navigation bar size and status bar size are much smaller than the one on appstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your app runs on scaled mode in ios 8.
And you probably put launch screen story board or set Main storyboard as launch screen.

Use static launch screen. But make sure launch screen is for "IOS 7.0 and Later". Don't set it as "IOS 8.0 and later"